# Mysql query - can't figure out a way to do this

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`game_id`, `first`, `second`, `third`)
VALUES
    (1, 'jack', 'joe', 'pat'),
    (2, 'jack', 'joe', 'jess'),
    (3, 'pat', 'jess', 'jack'),
    (4, 'pat', 'jess', 'jack');
```

This is a stats table that has the top three players for each game. I'm looking to pull all of the players and order them accordingly.

```
First place - 3 points
Second place - 2 points
Third place - 1 point
```

So, it should return:

```
id  player  points
1   jack    8
2   pat     7
3   jess    5
4   joe     4
```

I can't figure out a way to do this with one query.

Comment: You shouldn't have strings in your table, you also shouldn't name a table table

Comment: @Ghost The actual table is more complex and consists of only numbers. I made this one for this question.

Comment: @Ghost Why shouldn't the table have strings in it?

Comment: Why do you have a duplicate `game_id`?

Comment: @octern because he should have a seperate players table with playerid and name and then use the id in the games table

Comment: I feel like you can make a column just to store the points for each player in the player table. Use transaction to update the score each time you insert the new ranking

Comment: @Ghost Ah, they shouldn't have strings in *this* table. Yes, I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select player, sum(points) as points from (
Select `first` as player, count(`first`)*3 as points From gameStats group by `first` 
union all
Select `second` as player, count(`second`)*2 as points From gameStats group by `second` 
union all
Select `third` as player, count(`third`)*1 as points From gameStats group by `third` ) as tmp group by player
```

This should do it.

Let me Know if you need any more help.